# Adding labels to ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to do a bar plot outlined in black with percentages inside the bars.  Is this possible from qplot? I get the percentages to appear but they don't align with the particular bars.

packages: ggplot2, reshape

[image: created in Illustrator]

```
x <- data.frame(filename = c("file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"),
                    low = c(-.05,.06,.07,-.14),
                    hi = c(.87,.98,.56,.79))
x$tot <- x$hi + x$low

x <- melt(x, id = 'filename')

bar <- qplot(x = factor(filename), 
             y = value*100,
             fill = factor(variable),
             data = x,
             geom = 'bar',
             position = 'dodge') + coord_flip()
bar <- bar + scale_fill_manual(name = '',
                               labels = c('low',
                                          'Hi',
                                          "Tot"),
                               values = c('#40E0D0',
                                          '#FF6347',
                                          "#C7C7C7")) 
bar <- bar + geom_text(aes(label = value*100))+geom_bar(colour = 'black')
bar <- bar + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(colour = NA))
bar <- bar + opts(legend.justification = 'bottom')
print(bar)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since you are making use of non base R functions, please add a reference to the packages needed to reproduce your code, i.e. `library(...)`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(x, aes(x = filename, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", ymin=0, aes(y=value, ymax=value), position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(x=filename, y=value, ymax=value, label=value, 
                hjust=ifelse(sign(value)>0, 1, 0)), 
            position = position_dodge(width=1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the geom_text portion. Can you explain the ymax variable reasoning?

Comment: Oh, sorry - it's possibly redundant. I had to fight a little bit with some weird warnings. Try to remove it and see what happens.

Comment: Just wanted to note that `library(scales)` is needed for percent_format()

Answer (score 6):

This would be a good opportunity for you to start moving away from using `qplot`, in favor of `ggplot`. This will be much easier in the long run, trust me.

Here's a start:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(data = x,aes(x = factor(filename),y = value)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(variable)),colour = "black",position = 'dodge') + 
    coord_flip() + 
    scale_fill_manual(name = '',
                      labels = c('low',
                                 'Hi',
                                 "Tot"),
                      values = c('#40E0D0',
                                 '#FF6347',
                                 "#C7C7C7")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

For philosophical reasons, I will leave the annotation piece to you...

Comment: Thanks.  There still isn't text/percentages on the plot.  Do I pass 'value' to the percent_format()?

Comment: @RwardBound I know. I deliberately omitted the text labels because I am philosophically opposed to labeling bar charts in that manner. (But if you _were_ to make the labels, you wouldn't use anything in `scale_y_continuous`.)

Comment: I see.  What do you personally prefer? And how would I add the text please? very grateful for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the outline, but I gave the check to Andrie.

Comment: @RwardBound No problem! I suspected someone else would show you.