# Plot values over bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I didn't use `r` but I have recently decided to use it to plot graphs – because of its great capability to do so.
I would like to make my graph better. Specifically, I'd plot numbers over bars.
I saw [Adding labels to ggplot bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653268/adding-labels-to-ggplot-bar-chart) and I tried to use

```
geom_text(aes(x=years, y=freq, ymax=freq, label=value, 
                hjust=ifelse(sign(value)>0, 1, 0)), 
            position = position_dodge(width=1)) +
```

But the numbers failed to show up.

Here's my code:

```
# Load ggplot2 graphics package
library(ggplot2)

# Create dataset
dat <- data.frame(years = c("1991", "1993", "1997", "2001", "2005", "2007", "2011", "2015"),
freq = c(43.20, 52.13, 47.93, 46.29, 40.57, 53.88, 48.92, 50.92))

# Plot dataset with ggplot2
ggplot(dat, aes(years, freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.55)
+ labs(x="Year",y="") + theme_classic()

# Comma as decimal mark
format(df, decimal.mark=",")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ggplot2 you can achieve this by using `geom_text()`. `aes()` for this geometry needs to be provided with what is to be displayed (`label`) and the positioning.

You may use `format` in the call of `aes()` to get the comma as a decimal separator.

```
 ggplot(dat, aes(years, freq)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.55) +
    geom_text(aes(label=format(freq,decimal.mark = ","), y=freq+1.1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,50,10)) + 
    theme_classic()
```

It's slightly more idiomatic to do:

```
 library(scales)

 ggplot(dat, aes(years, freq)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.55) +
    geom_text(aes(label=comma(freq), y=freq+1.1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,50,10)) + 
    theme_classic()
```

as the `scales` package has many handy labelers built-in.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've made one change: `y=freq+2` and the values are a bit higher now. @hrbrmstr please feel free to supply your more idiomatic code.

Comment: M. A. has it covered here. Tis a gd answer (and I just added the idiomatic vs to it). You can use `nudge_y` std param vs adding to the `aes()` `y` param to move the label as well.

Comment: When I use your more idiomatic code I get : `Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(y = c(44.3, 53.23, 49.03, 47.39, 41.67, 54.98, 50.02,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 0`

Comment: Was in a hurry before and forgot the parameter. Fixed.